# How to find the mount point for a partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount

The title say it all :

I insert a memory card, 
I know its device label (`/dev/sde1`),
I also know it's automatically mounted by Ubuntu.

Therefore, presuming it's already mounted, how do I ***find*** the mount point of this partition ?

Already looked into `/media`, couldn't find anything.

Note : I can't use GUI, only console commands. Otherwise I would use `disks`.

*Edit* : Many thanks, all answers provided below are good and work well. I wish I could elect them all.
I selected @steeldriver 's `findmnt` as it's the answer which matches the question the closest, but there is definitely good things to say and to know from other solutions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `findmnt` command.

```
findmnt /dev/sde1
```

Ex.

```
$ findmnt -notarget /dev/sda5
/usr/local
```

where

```
   -n, --noheadings
          Do not print a header line.

   -o, --output list
          Define output columns.
```

Answer (score 1):

use /proc/mounts - it contains all the current mount information, so for /dev/sde1 use:

```
grep /dev/sde1 /proc/mounts
```

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way: `df`

- Let's use df to discover that /dev/sda1 is mounted at /

  ```
   $ df -h | grep sda1
   /dev/sda1        29G   20G  7.5G  73% /
  ```
- Let's use df and exclude all those snaps:

  ```
    $ df -h | grep -v loop
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           378M  1.9M  376M   1% /run
    /dev/sda1        29G   20G  7.5G  73% /
    tmpfs           1.9G  180M  1.7G  10% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
    tmpfs           378M   20K  378M   1% /run/user/120
    tmpfs           378M   44K  378M   1% /run/user/1000
  ```

Comment: Thanks ! I love the simplicity of this solution !

Answer (score 1):

`lsblk` is probably what you need. This is a built-in command available on most *nix systems.

This will show a list of all block devices that exist on the system and where they are mounted to - if they are mounted.

Comment: Thanks ! I didn't know this command, and it's definitely worth knowing !